# TCP connection using RFCOMM sockets over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using TCP over RFCOMM socket for client server communication over bluetooth
My server is Linux based machine and clients are android phones.
The issue I am facing is sometimes pairing takes long time and the error that I get on my android phone is "failed to connect with the peer".
If I get through the pairing process then establishing TCP connection is also painful and it fails randomly.

Is there specific method/steps to make pairing and connection establishment much more reliable and seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to take a dump on the server side BT interface? You can use the following commands:

- `hcidump -a`
- `btmon`

to capture the packets.

Comment: I will try both of these commands . This might help in understanding what are the packets getting exchanged between two bt peers. Any particular bytes you want me to check in btmon or hcidump output which will help debugging problem??